# В сборке не корректно отображается UI

Tags: unity3d, ui

Создал обычный UI путем добавления в иерархию объектов объекты с компонентами *`UI/Text`* и *`UI/Image`*.

В редакторе все отображается нормально:

[image: все отображается в редакторе]

В билде:

[image: не корректно отображается UI]

Похоже на то как будто нет материала в `TMP`, но **это дефолтные** UI компоненты движка. Создал новый проект с нуля и на пустой сцене накинул UI, сбилдил, результат тот же, если кто то встречал подобную проблему прошу подсказать.
Использую старую версию `Unity 2017.3.1f1` (необходимо по работе). П.С. что странно - на другом проджекте той же версии движка все работает в билде, не могу найти в чем проблема.

Comment: Удали папку Library в директории проекта(естественно пока Unity закрыт), а потом запусти проект. Обычно помогает, если юнити кричит про отсутствие файлов или чего то подобного, а в твоём случае, похоже, отсутствует какой то компонент, связанный с UI

Comment: удалил, к сожалению не помогло, в консоли не ругается не на что